# SQL to find a string in another string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables:

**tblFoo**:

```
Id | MessageId | SenderName
```

**tblBar**:

```
MessageId | Name
```

I need to update all the rows in tblFoo with the MessageId from tblBar where SenderName starts with Name. e.g.

**tblFoo**:

```
Id     | MessageId | SenderName
-------+-----------+--------------------
365175 | NULL      | x.y.z.abc.def.ghi
535646 | NULL      | a.b.c.fjdkf.dsfjdsf:a
535647 | NULL      | a.b.c.sdjskfj.dsfjds:b
```

**tblBar**:

```
MessageId                             | Name
--------------------------------------+--------
9B30FCD1-F063-4B7F-887B-65288C3681D3  | x.y.z
56FBEF0F-8C29-4614-8894-4F64A515659A  | a.b.c
```

So in `tblFoo` `Id=365175` would end up with `MessageId = 9B30FCD1-F063-4B7F-887B-65288C3681D3` and `Id=535646` would end up with `MessageId = 56FBEF0F-8C29-4614-8894-4F64A515659A` and `Id=535647` would also end up with `MessageId=
56FBEF0F-8C29-4614-8894-4F64A515659A`

So far I have

```
begin transaction
    update tblFoo
    set MessageId = 
    (
        select MessageId
        from tblBar
        where [Name] ???
    );
    rollback transaction
```

I can't do

```
where [Name] like
```

as [Name] is a substring of SenderName.

Or do I need to use a temp table?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Is it possible, that there are more than one entries in `tblBar`, where the `Name` matches the `SenderName`? However, you are looking for something like `LIKE SenderName=tblBar.Name + '%'`...

Comment: No, there *shouldn't* be more than one match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the inner join as below.

```
update foo set messageid = br.messageid
from
tblFoo foo
inner join 
tblBar br 
on foo.senderName like ltrim(br.Name) + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like SQL Server.  You can do this using something like:

```
update h
    set MessageDefinitionId = (select MessageDefinitionId
                               from Sentilan2.msg.tblMessageDefinition md
                               where h.SenderName like md.[Name] + '%'
                              );
    from h;
```

Your code is rather hard to follow because you define tables `tblFoo` and `tblBar`, but the sample code uses different table names.

Also note that this assumes that there is only one match.  You might want `top 1` in the subquery to avoid run-time errors.